# Preview Different images on HTML Form

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML form with multiple inputs for uploading pics. I need to preview each of those pics after I click Choose File button:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#img1").change(function() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
  });
});

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
  $('#myImg1').attr('src', e.target.result);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <input id="img1" name="img1" type="file" /> </td>
    <td> <img id="myImg1" src="#" alt="your image" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input id="img2" name="img2" type="file" /> </td>
    <td> <img id="myImg2" src="#" alt="your image" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <input id="img3" name="img3" type="file" /> </td>
    <td> <img id="myImg3" src="#" alt="your image" /> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Previewing multiple is the same as previewing one, you just need to loop over each file control. Seeing your code would help us diagnose any of your issues.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan 

Edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can place common classes on all the file inputs and `img` elements. From there you can use DOM traversal to find the `img` related to the input and update it's `src` attribute when a file is selected. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.img').change(function() {
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var $view = $(this).closest('tr').find('.view');
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $view.attr('src', e.target.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="img1" name="img1" type="file" class="img" /> </td>
    <td><img id="myImg1" src="#" alt="your image" class="view" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="img2" name="img2" type="file" class="img" /> </td>
    <td><img id="myImg2" src="#" alt="your image" class="view" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="img3" name="img3" type="file" class="img" /> </td>
    <td><img id="myImg3" src="#" alt="your image" class="view" /> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```